# dropzone.js php upload don't work

Tags: javascript, php, file, file-upload, upload

unfortunately my "[dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)" dont work, i followed this tutorial:

http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php

my ordner structure is the same as mentioned in the tutorial

okay so i have my index.php:

```
<html>

<head>   

<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="../css/style.less"/>
<script src="../scripts/less.js"> </script>
<script src="../scripts/dropzone.js"> </script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- 3 -->
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone">

</form>

</body>

</html>>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

}
?>
```

everything looks good exept theres no file in my uploads folder.
I got no erros but im not sure if my error reporting is correct.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I just tried it, and it work completely fine. Are you sure you don't get any error? Do you get any in javascript console on your browser? Make sure the file you upload is under the limit size of server. Try add `print_r($_FILES);` after `$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2` to see what happened to the files

Comment: i got it now working :) file was way too big, stupid me. Thanks

Comment: Haha, it usually happens. Btw, please make your question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above works fine. I got it working after realizing my file was just too big.